# Complete Load Balancing solution

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I have a Laravel web application based on MariaDB, PHP, Nginx, and ubuntu 20.04. To ensure that my website is always online under heavy traffic, I decided to establish load balancing between my servers. I'm using the Galera cluster for the database and Rsync for the file synchronization. But I don't want to have only one Nginx reverse_proxy server to distribute traffic between my servers. Because it's risky since if the reverse proxy server goes down, it will take down the whole website.

So here is the question, How can I distribute the traffic between two Nginx reverse proxies? The two Nginx reverse proxy servers should point to my website domain

Answer (score 1):

You put two haproxy servers in front of the nginx servers, of which only one handles the traffic, the other one is kept in standby by keepalived.

Comment: What if the traffic takes down the HAproxy server??

Comment: That's not traffic, that needs a DDOS, against which you can perhaps - perhaps! - protect your site with a CDN.  Does your site generate enough to pay for that?  Also, Laravel will go down long before HaProxy or Nginx.

Comment: I thought your question was "How can I distribute ...".

Comment: using cdn is fine but here is my question. If the first haproxy goes down for any reason(other than ddos). how can I set the first server's IP to second one?? as you know changing server IP address need time to be available to internet dns servers.

Comment: That is, as I said, the task of keepalived.  In case of a problem, the standby system takes over the service IP address.  No DNS involved.

Comment: Don't forget you need two routers from different ISP's too.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial articles for that?? Can you share it to me please??

Comment: No I don't.  I used this setup in production for years before I retired.  Nothing could bring it down apart from bad programming on the backends.

Comment: Tools used:  keepalived, haproxy, varnish, nginx or apache in front of different backend system.